# Iteratively loading and filtering table [R] [Shiny]

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm having trouble iteratively loading and filtering a datatable in Shiny. The ideal workflow would be as follows:

1. User pushes button to confirm loading data
2. Data is retrieved from MySql query. Note this should only occur once
3. (optional) filter buttons/sliders become visible/available
4. User interacts with buttons/sliders to filter datatable

1 and 2 work fine, but I am having particular issue with 4 (also any input for 3 would be appreciated as well).

The initial code that is not working is as follows:

```
get_data=function(){ # note that this is for sample purpose, real function is MySQL query
  df=data.frame(x=1:10,Age=1:100)
  print("loading data...")
return(df)
}

ui = bootstrapPage(
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      actionButton(
        inputId = "confirm_button",
        label = "Confirm"
      )
    )
    ,
    fluidRow(
      column(4,

             sliderInput("slider_age", label = h4("Age"), min = 0, 
                         max = 100, value = c(0, 100))
      )
    ),

    hr(),

    fluidRow(
      DT::dataTableOutput("all_background_table") 
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output){


observeEvent(input$confirm_button, {

  req(input$confirm_button) 


  output$all_background_table <- DT::renderDataTable({

    all_background=get_data() # <- MySQL function to laod data

    # if all_background filter function put here: 
    #--> data is re-loaded by MySQL query

    # if all_background filter function is put here surrounded by observeEvent(input$slider_age, {...:
    #--> there is no change when input$slider_age is changed

    datatable(all_background,
              rownames = FALSE,
              style = "bootstrap")

  })  


})

  observeEvent(input$slider_age, {
    ## this will throw an error requiring all_background
    #--> Error in observeEventHandler: object 'all_background' not found

    req(input$confirmation_load_pts)  

    all_background=all_background[(all_background$Age > as.numeric(input$slider_age[1]) &  all_background$Age < as.numeric(input$slider_age[2])),]

  })

}  

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Please provide the full shiny app.

Comment: Don't know how to do this with the MySQL query, but i will edit to provide a sample

Comment: You can use a subset of your data. Enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't quite follow...Regardless I added the app layout as well as a sample dataframe which, while not the real data, should still serve the purpose I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about get_data(), but I will be using `df` to make it easier. With `eventReactive` you can create a new data frame after using the slider and only after clicking on the confirm button. Your `observeEvent`would not be necessary for this scenario.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
get_data=function(){ # note that this is for sample purpose, real function is MySQL query
  df=data.frame(x=1:10,Age=1:100)
  print("loading data...")
return(df)
}
ui = bootstrapPage(
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      actionButton(
        inputId = "confirm_button",
        label = "Confirm"
      )
    )
    ,
    fluidRow(
      column(4,

             sliderInput("slider_age", label = h4("Age"), min = 0, 
                         max = 100, value = c(0, 100))
      )
    ),

    hr(),

    fluidRow(
      DT::dataTableOutput("all_background_table") 
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output){

  test <- eventReactive(input$confirm_button, {
    df=get_data()


  })  

  observeEvent(input$confirm_button, {

    output$all_background_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      df=test() 

      all_background2=df[(df$Age > as.numeric(input$slider_age[1]) &  df$Age < as.numeric(input$slider_age[2])),]


      datatable(all_background2,
                rownames = FALSE,
                style = "bootstrap")

    })  


  })

}  

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am getting a "Warning: Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" error. Will investigate

Comment: maybe start a new session. I just added the libraries and df=data.frame(x=1:10,Age=1:100) to the code. But it work as it is.

Comment: ah- I think library(DT is missing closing ")". testing out now. thanks

Comment: hmm I apologize if I was confusing, but I can't have the data preloaded when the app starts. it should only be generated when the button is pressed. appreciate your help so far, I will continue to play around with it!

Comment: @ben it works the same if I replace df with df=get_data()

Comment: I realize that functionally it will work the same, but there are many reasons why I prefer the data to load _after_ the button is pressed.

1) the app has multiple panels, so multiple datasets will be loaded, only when needed

2) the queries can take a few minutes, so I would not want them to run if not necessary

3) because the queries take some time, ideally the data would be loaded once...and filtered from the loaded data (i.e. not generated again each time the slider is changed). It is also important because there will be other filtering options/buttons as well

Comment: my answer is using your post and the same `get_data` function you are using. Please more specific in your original post.

Comment: oh- i apologize, didn't see you edited...originally you had:
df=data.frame(x=1:10,Age=1:100)
will try out now. thanks again

Comment: So ideally, the slider/buttons should be reactive, i.e. the user does not have to press Confirm each time to load the data. The workflow ideally would be as follows:

1. User pushes button to confirm loading data 
2. Data is retrieved from MySql query. (Note this should only occur once)
3. User interacts with buttons/sliders to filter datatable (Note data is not reloaded, simply filtered)

this would be like if you search, i.e.:
"Showing 1 to 10 of 19 entries (filtered from 99 total entries) "

Apologies if this is confusing on my part

Comment: @ben see edits. the slider is reactive and you don't need to click the button each time

Comment: glad it helped!